# C# ip to hex to decimal

Tags: c#

I need to read computers ip adress, which is already done. After that I need to change the recieved ip value to hex and then to decimal, basically like this

`127.0.0.1` flip the value to `1.0.0.127` to hex `0100007F` and finally to `16777343`.

```
public static string GetLocalIPAddress()
    {
        var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {

                string hexValue = ip.ToString();
                string cleanAmount = hexValue.Replace(".", string.Empty);
                Console.Write(cleanAmount + "\n");
                return ip.ToString();
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("No network adapters with an IPv4 address in the system!");
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetLocalIPAddress();
    }
```

Comment: What issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: the `ip.ToString()` returns a "dotted decimal" value, not "hex". By removing the `.` you loose the distinction between "1.21" and "12.1"

Comment: Firstly you need to define what your expected behaviour is e.g. 100172 in hex is 1871F. 1000000127 is 3B9ACA7F. 1 in hex is 1, 0 is 0, 127 is 7F. If you want to treat the octets individually (which it seems you possibly do?) then it is best to separate them whilst they are delimited rather than remove the delimiter

Comment: There are plenty of good answers here, best pick your  favorite

Answer (score 4):

Here you go

```
string input = "127.0.0.1";
string hex = string.Concat(input.Split('.').Reverse().Select(x => int.Parse(x).ToString("X").PadLeft(2,'0'))); // 0100007F 
int result = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16); //16777343
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Convert.ToString` to convert an `int` from decimal to a different numeral system:

```
Convert.ToString(127, 16); //16 for hexadecimal
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to reverse anything at all?
You could just read each group and multiply its value by 256^rank:

```
static void Main()
{
    string ip = "127.0.0.1";

    string[] splitted = ip.Split('.');

    int value = 0;
    int factor = 1;

    for(int i=0;i<splitted.Length;i++)
    {
        value += factor*Convert.ToInt32(splitted[i]);
        factor*=256;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Writes `16777343`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";
string[] parts = ipAddress.Split('.');
string hexResult = "";
// loop backwards, to reverese order of parts of IP
for (int i = parts.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    hexResult += int.Parse(parts[i]).ToString("X").PadLeft(2, '0');
int finalResult = Convert.ToInt32(hexResult, 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends why you want this reversed, and if this is an endian issue

essentially you just need to return your int

```
BitConverter.ToInt64(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1").GetAddressBytes(), 0);
```

Or a more verbose example

```
var bytes = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1").GetAddressBytes();

if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
   Array.Reverse(bytes);

for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    Console.Write(bytes[i].ToString("X2"));

Console.WriteLine("");

long r = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
Console.WriteLine(r);
```

**Output**

```
7F000001 
16777343
```

[Full Demo Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ElU59P)

Comment: IP addresses are in network byte order i.e. big endian, so to convert to an IPv4 address to a long that should be if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)

Comment: for some reason if I use `Array.Reverse(bytes)` it returns me a -1062728671 with my computers own ip, if not reversed returns 554477760

Comment: @Fuppetia Make sure you use long, and not int